# Google Workspace bigquery ip_address is not always base64 correct

Tags: google-bigquery, google-workspace

I've set up a Google Workspace report/log export to BigQuery as per [the official guide](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9079365?hl=en). In the activity log, the field ip_address is BYTES and contains Base64 encoded IP address associated with the record.

I want to search all records for a specific ip address, so I do:

```
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.activity` 
WHERE  ip_address IS NOT NULL 
AND  FROM_BASE64(CAST(ip_address AS STRING))=b'1.2.3.4' 
ORDER BY time_usec ASC LIMIT 10
```

However some rows appear to contain an invalid ip_address and I get the error: *"Failed to decode invalid base64 string"*

1. Is there a saner way to decode the IP addresses in this specific case?
2. How do I know *which* row caused the error?
3. How do I work around this error?

Comment: Are you able to share some sample data of `Base64 encoded IP address` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will generate same error you faced

```
-- sample data
WITH `project.dataset.activity` AS (
  SELECT 'a@b.com' email, CAST(TO_BASE64(b'1.2.3.4') AS BYTES) ip_address UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b@c.com' email, b'MS4yLjMuNA##' ip_address  --> invalid base64 string
)
SELECT FROM_BASE64(CAST(ip_address AS STRING)) FROM `project.dataset.activity`;

-- query result
☞ Failed to decode invalid base64 string
```

> 2. How do I know which row caused the error?

You can use [SAFE.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-reference#safe_prefix) prefix for this purpose. If base64 decoding fails, `SAFE.` prefixed function will return `null` as a result instead of quitting job with an error. Therefore you can identify which row has a problem from the result. In the sample, you can see that the second row has a problem.

```sql
SELECT *, SAFE.FROM_BASE64(CAST(ip_address AS STRING)) decoded FROM `project.dataset.activity`;
```

**query result**

[image]

---

If applied to your query,

```sql
-- sample data
WITH `project.dataset.activity` AS (
  SELECT 'a@b.com' email, CAST(TO_BASE64(b'1.2.3.4') AS BYTES) ip_address UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b@c.com' email, b'MS4yLjMuNA##' ip_address  --> invalid base64 string
)
-- query starts here
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.activity` 
 WHERE ip_address IS NOT NULL 
   AND SAFE.FROM_BASE64(CAST(ip_address AS STRING)) = b'1.2.3.4';

-- query result
+---------+------------------+
|  email  |    ip_address    |
+---------+------------------+
| a@b.com | TVM0eUxqTXVOQT09 |
+---------+------------------+
```